# dual booting 16.04

Tags: dual-boot

Installing Ubuntu 16.04.1 on laptop. Correctly partitioned my hard drive (shrunk volume) for 60gb's. Used Rufus for transferring Ubuntu onto USB drive(chose iso image), which has a capacity of 4gb's. Boot into bios. I've tried so many combinations in here, legacy modes, uefi mode, safe boot mode enabled/disabled, ranking my usb stick higher then my windows boot, and when I get to the Ubuntu installation menu, I click install Ubuntu, it takes me to enter my wifi password, I hit next, then it says not enough room, "atleast 8gb's is needed and you have only 4gb available", so it seems like it is recognizing my usb drive as my hard drive, and won't recognize anything I partitioned. So confused and frustrated as I have never before had problems installing Ubuntu, any advice is appreciated.

Here are some more images: (I have one more of the security menu, but can only post 2 links at a time because my rep is <10, I'm sure I can comment it if someone wants to see what that set up looks like)

http://i67.tinypic.com/14kbe34.jpg

http://i66.tinypic.com/2dcbgjq.jpg

Comment: okay so should I make my default hard drive (shows up as Samsung I think) higher priority then my usb drive(transit or Toshiba as it shows up)? I am installing the USB drive because that is where Ubuntu is at, not on my hard drive that is partitioned... I'm kind of confused by what you said possibly.

Comment: UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu Then use Something else to choose(change button) the  partition you created as / (root) with ext4. Same if you created another partition for /home. If swap already created it will find it automatically. http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi Similar: http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: Boot from the USB

Comment: I added that output below. I couldn't edit my question and post the links because my rep is <10.

Answer (score 2):

Choose Something else as the option in the installer and adjust your usage of the existing partitions accordingly. Without the output of `sudo fdisk -l` I can't tell you much more.

Comment: What all can I choose? Either my hard drive or my USB stick, correct? Also, where can I enter that at? I'm glad to give you the output, I just want to get this installed.

Comment: Boot the live media, Choose Try Ubuntu, Open as terminal and enter `sudo fdisk -l` then [edit] your question and paste in  the output of `sudo fdisk -l` Comment when done and I'll take another look.

Comment: Here is the output: http://i68.tinypic.com/qxlxjd.jpg      http://i63.tinypic.com/2v3lw0z.jpg

Comment: My apologies but despite my best efforts I cannot read the text in the picture. Please [edit] your question and paste the text into it.

Comment: http://i66.tinypic.com/2ztjdyq.png     Is this better?

Comment: text please and [edit] it into your question. Comments are second class citizens here and get removed for a number of reasons

Comment: okay, let me figure out how to do that from a screenshot...

Comment: I provided instruction on how to do it above. The comment that begins with "Boot the live media" once you have the output from running the command simply highlight it and copy it. Return to this page and click [edit] and paste the output into your question.

Comment: ahh, well I just tried the option "try without installing ubuntu", the wifi won't connect, and my connection is not the problem. I tried getting in the terminal and running several commands, such as "sudo rmmod ideapad_laptop" I'm not sure what else to do, this is frustrating, honestly thinking about going to buy a mac book air for my programming needs

Comment: If all else fails you can redirect the output with `sudo fdisl -l > disk.layout`, copy the resulting disk.layout file to portable media and bring it to a system with internet access, Return to this page and click [edit] and paste the output into your question